# How to simplify this postgres query

Tags: performance, postgresql

How can I simplify this query?

What I am trying to do is derive the column S9_Unlock via a subquery in which I only look for user_ids which are returned from the main query but this looks very awkward to me, especially as this query here is just an excerpt. In reality I am doing multiple of these subqueries to derive different columns...

```
SELECT userid, CAST(to_char(S9_unlock,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS timestamp) AS "S9_Unlock"
FROM (
  SELECT ca.user_id AS userid
  FROM shop_db.invoices AS inv
  LEFT JOIN shop_db.carts AS ca ON inv.id = ca.invoice_id
  LEFT JOIN shop_db.cart_items AS ci ON ca.id = ci.cart_id
  WHERE (inv.created BETWEEN '2014-11-13' AND '2014-11-14' OR inv.created BETWEEN '2013-11-14' AND '2013-11-15')
    AND inv.status <> 'do_not_book'
    AND inv.id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY user_id) AS master
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(s3.unl) AS "S9_Unlock", s3.user_id
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, challenge_codes.created AS unl,
           MAX /* Check if license contains Suite9 */
             (CASE WHEN substring(bundle_article_code,1,6) = 'BuSu90' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "S9_Unlock"
    FROM licensing_db.serial_numbers
    LEFT JOIN licensing_db.licenses ON licenses.id = serial_numbers.license_id 
    LEFT JOIN user_db.users ON users.id = licenses.user_id
    LEFT JOIN licensing_db.challenge_codes ON challenge_codes.serial_number_id = serial_numbers.id
    WHERE user_id IN (
      SELECT ca.user_id AS userid
      FROM shop_db.invoices AS inv
      LEFT JOIN shop_db.carts AS ca ON inv.id = ca.invoice_id
      LEFT JOIN shop_db.cart_items AS ci ON ca.id = ci.cart_id
      WHERE (inv.created BETWEEN '2014-11-13' AND '2014-11-14' OR inv.created BETWEEN '2013-11-14' AND '2013-11-15')
        AND inv.status <> 'do_not_book'
        AND inv.id IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY user_id
    )
    GROUP BY user_id, challenge_codes.created) AS s3
  )
  WHERE "S9_Unlock" = 1
    AND s3.unl IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY s3.user_id) AS "S9_Unlock" ON "S9_Unlock".user_id = master.userid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have two sub-queries that are identical; this screams for a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html).

In the sub-query on licensing issues you can filter out the valid licenses after the `GROUP BY` clause using a `HAVING` clause. Make that a `WITH QUERY` too and you end up with the rather more readable:

```
WITH inv AS (
  SELECT ca.user_id AS userid
  FROM shop_db.invoices AS inv
  LEFT JOIN shop_db.carts AS ca ON ca.invoice_id = inv.id
  LEFT JOIN shop_db.cart_items AS ci ON ci.cart_id = ca.id
  WHERE (inv.created BETWEEN '2014-11-13' AND '2014-11-14' OR inv.created BETWEEN '2013-11-14' AND '2013-11-15')
    AND inv.status <> 'do_not_book'
    AND inv.id IS NOT NULL
), s3 AS (
    SELECT u.user_id, min(cc.created) AS first_unlocked, bundle_article_code
    FROM licensing_db.serial_numbers AS sn
    LEFT JOIN licensing_db.licenses AS lic ON lic.id = sn.license_id 
    LEFT JOIN user_db.users AS u ON u.id = lic.user_id
    LEFT JOIN licensing_db.challenge_codes AS cc ON cc.serial_number_id = sn.id
    WHERE u.user_id IN (SELECT userid FROM inv)
    GROUP BY u.user_id, bundle_article_code
    HAVING bundle_article_code LIKE 'BuSu90%'
       AND first_unlocked IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT userid, date_trunc('day', first_unlocked) AS "S9_Unlock"
FROM inv
LEFT JOIN s3 ON s3.user_id = inv.userid;
```

So the main query is now reduced to 3 lines and both the `WITH-QUERY`'s perform a logically self-contained query of the database. The other sub-queries you refer to can similarly become a `WITH-QUERY` and then you assemble them in the main query. Remember that you can refer to earlier named queries in the list of with-queries, as is shown above with `inv` being referred to by `s3`. While such CTE's are syntactically not providing new functionality (except for the `RECURSIVE` variant), they do make complex queries much more readable and therefore easier to maintain.

Another approach would be to factor out logical sub-components (such as the `inv` sub-query) and make a `VIEW` out of those. Then you can simply reference the view in the main query. Making the whole thing a view is probably also a good idea if you want to make the query more flexible. What if you want to query for Suite9.1 ('BuSu91%') on 27 March 2014? Taken those literals out and then using them as `WHERE` clauses in a view makes your query more versatile; this can be either with sub-queries or with the complete CTE.

(Please check if the semantics are still right in the `s3` with-query because without your table structures and sample data I ccannot test my code above.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. That's definitely more readable. I will give this a try and then give you some feedback. However, my concern is that, that the "min(cc.created)" won't yield the right results, instead I expect it to return multiple rows (if these exist) instead of just one. Let's see

Comment: The `s3` sub-query will indeed return a record for every `user_id` that bought Suite9 on the date ranges in the `inv` sub-query. Your original query effectively selects the `user_id` which bought the largest number of Suite9 on those dates; I took that as a complicated way of implementing the comment (check if any Suite9 was bought).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving your problem as one big monolithic relational sql query, I would seriously consider going the "procedural" way, by using the built-in "plpgsql" language of postgresql. This could bring a lot of clarity in your application.

Comment: What do you mean by that?